# Switching signing keys for my android App

Tags: android

I need to recompile my Android Store App (fully working and deployed) again to ask for a higher targetSdk as per the mail from google asked me to. If I don't do this, then it will not be shown in the store anymore.

The problem was it was a long time since I've done this and I had lost the password and name that you need to entered for creating the release bundle. This was also my first time creating an .aab file, because all previous times I created an apk.

But the app-release.aab was created. When I try to upload it, I get this message:

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: 
SHA1: SHA-CHECKSUM-HERE
```

However I don't have the key. I have now saved the .jks and the .pepk file for future reference. But how do I tell the play console that I'm now signing with another key.

I have contacted google support as suggested by the play console. The weird thing is that It told me I would be contacted in two business days. But not only this has not happened, but I didn't get an email telling me that I had submitted a request or anything like that. This is my first time doing this, so is this normal?

Please advice, if this is not the right place, where I should ask this question.

How should I proceed?

Comment: It's not possible to change signing key. From the docs - `However, if you lose your keystore or it becomes compromised, you won’t be able to update your app without publishing a new app with a new package name.` You can get your old signing key if you registered with `Google Play App Signing`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the support doesn't help you to solve this, the only solution is to rename your package and create a new key. So you will have theoretically a new app with another package. Not sure if the name of the app must be different too.

Comment: But If I do this, people with the app alredy won't get any updates in the future right? They would need to redownload the app?

Comment: Also is ti common for your mail to to just fall into nothingness like this? Shouldn't you at least get some sort fo "we are processing your query" or something?